# SP Online site collection ID

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, office-365, pnp-powershell, site-template

I need to create an SP online Team site (with Office 365 group) with PowerShell.

Can you please help me find the Template ID for the Team site (with Office 365 group)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the article [SharePoint Online Site Template ID list for PowerShell](https://vladtalkstech.com/2019/12/sharepoint-online-site-template-id-list-for-powershell.html), template ID for Office 365 Group associated Team Site is **GROUP#0** - which is **For Reporting Only** and you cannot create sites with this template.

So, you can use PnP PowerShell to create a team site with Office 365 group.

Example:

```
New-PnPSite -Type TeamSite -Title 'Team Contoso' -Alias contoso
```

**Documentation**: [New-PnPSite](https://pnp.github.io/powershell/cmdlets/New-PnPSite.html)